# Python: create new column and copy value from other row which is a swap of current row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has 3 columns:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A':  ['left', 'right', 'east', 'west', 'south', 'north'], 'B': ['right', 'left', 'west', 'east', 'north', 'south'], 'VALUE': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
  A       B   VALUE
left    right   0
right   left    1
east    west    2
west    east    3
south   north   4
north   south   5
```

I am trying to create a new column VALUE_2 which should contain the value from the swapped row in the same Dataframe.

> Eg: right - left value is 0, left - right value is 1 and I want the swapped values in the new column like this:

```
  A       B   VALUE VALUE_2
left    right   0     1
right   left    1     0
east    west    2     3
west    east    3     2
south   north   4     5
north   south   5     4
```

I tried:

```
for row_num, record in df.iterrows():
    A = df['A'][index]
    B = df['B'][index]
    if(pd.Series([record['A'] == B, record['B'] == A).all()):
        df['VALUE_2'] = df['VALUE']
```

I'm struck here, inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df['VALUE_2'] = df['A'].map(df.set_index('B')['VALUE'])
print (df)
       A      B  VALUE  VALUE_2
0   left  right      0        1
1  right   left      1        0
2   east   west      2        3
3   west   east      3        2
4  south  north      4        5
5  north  south      5        4
```

Comment: Great, works well. If I have 4 columns A, B, C, D with the same condition of swap (A,B & C,D), how do I go about that? Hint please.

Comment: @Pokemon - do you think pairs of columns? Can you add some date sample, 3-4 rows?

Comment: Yes, for example A, B, C, D, VALUE are columns, 1st row is: (x, y, z, p, 100), 2nd row: (z, p, x, y, 50), 3rd row: (a, b, x, y, 200), 4th row: (x, y, a, b, 150) and so on. So, at any given point in time, only the column pairs A, B and C, D are swapped in the rows.

Comment: So need swap each 2 row groups? because `x,y` should be repalce by `z,p` or `a,b` in all data?

Comment: @Pokemon - how working `df = df.join(df.set_index(['A', 'B'])['VALUE'].rename('VALUE_2'), ['C','D'])` ? There are duplicates? Or correct?

Comment: so need swap each value for each 2 rows groups? like `df['new'] = df.groupby(df.index // 2)['VALUE'].agg([('a','last'),('b','first')]).stack().values` ?

Comment: This looks perfect! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a more verbose answer:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A':  ['left', 'right', 'east', 'west', 'south', 'north'], 'B': ['right', 'left', 'west', 'east', 'north', 'south'], 'VALUE': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

pdf = pd.DataFrame([])
for idx, item in df.iterrows():
    indx = list(df['B']).index(str(df['A'][idx]))
    pdf = pdf.append(pd.DataFrame({'VALUE_2': df.iloc[indx][2]}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)

print(pdf)
data = pd.concat([df, pdf], axis=1)
print(data)
```